# Which PMD rules to activate for JUnit tests?

Tags: junit, pmd

I'm in the middle of setting up [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) as a tool in our team to support us writing better code. Basically I'm building [Ant scripts](http://ant.apache.org/) and try to set up some rules for everyone to use.

But right now I hit this problem:

When I write [JUnit tests](http://junit.org) **I don't want to use the same rules I apply on our main source code**. I don't care that much about [String rules](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/rules/strings.html) (like string dupliates or weird instantiations) in the junit tests.

**My questions is:**

1. Is that a fault on my side and should I start writing better JUnit tests?
2. Should I provide a 2nd set of rules that disables some of the string/design/finalizers rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second option - I don't run PMD against my tests at all.  I could and PMD provides some JUnit specific rules.   I would definitely use a separate ruleset against the test code though.  I expect more String literals and some thing specified instead of using conditionals/loops.  After all, I don't want to duplicate the code I am trying to test.

Comment: I'll set up another ruleset configuration for my tests. There is some code duplication there and some string jumbling that I don't see as a code smell.

Answer (score 1):

Two things. Why are you trying to set up rules why not using the existing rules? (Special requirements?). And second yes of course Unit tests should have a good quality as well. Your Unit test test you production code so shouldn't they have at least the same quality as your production code?

Comment: Ah, I'm not creating new rules all by myself, I'm only selecting from the existing rules. I don't need some rules in my project, for example I disable the j2ee rules. And our existing codebase will result in thousands of warnings if I don't disable some of the rules.

Comment: About the 2nd point, I want a high quality in my unit tests, but for example when I test an class that exports my objects in a text format, I'm using `Strings` in my `assert` statements a lot to check if the data is exported correct and PMD will give lots of warnings about String optimizations. That's something I thought turning off wouldn't affect the unit test quality much.